# Yii AR transaction: auto increment id returns null

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, transactions, auto-increment

In my Yii application I have this relation (Product has many Attribute), Product table primary key is auto increment, Attribute table has foreign key product_id to the related Product. 
When I use transaction in yii to save the parent (Product) and child (Attribute) I getting error (product_id cannot be blank), this happen because ($product->id) returns NULL after save inside the transaction.
Here is my code:

```
        $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->name = 'name_product';

        if ($product->save()) {
            $product_attribut = new ProductAtt;
            $product_attribut->product_id = $product->id;
            $product_attribut->name = 'att_name';
            $product_attribut->value = 22;
            if (!$product_attribut->save()) {
                throw new Exception('fail');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('fail');
        }

        $transaction->commit();
        echo 'success';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollback();
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Any idea to save this relation in transaction please .. thank you.

Comment: Did you try with `Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID()` instead of `$product->id` ?

Comment: will this method return the last id for the current DB connection or the last id globally across all connections. If it returns the last in current .. then I'm worry about if Yii is using singleton  pattern in the database connection

Comment: I have a similar code and works just fine. Your problem is not the transaction.
Are any errors from the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else is having this problem, I found solution that was not mentioned so far in all the similar questions I have read:

Make sure you have *assigned a primary key to your database*.  Even if you have an auto-increment field, this does not necessarily mean you have defined a primary key.
Yii reads the database schema and uses this information to determine what primary keys there are and subsequently how to update the primary keys in your record after insertion.  So even if your *ActiveRecord definition* has defined a primary key, this is not enough.

The Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID() actually works in this situation, however I am a dubious if this works in multi-session environments.  Defining a primary key is obviously the better solution if you haven't already.

Hope this helps others!